# RelationNotFoundException error only in laravel dispatched jobs

Tags: laravel, laravel-horizon

I have a very strange error in laravel 7 where I have defined a hasOne relationship in the User Model called user_badge

```
public function userBadge()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserBadge::class, 'id', 'user_badge_id');
}
```

I have added user_badge_id to the users table and I have also made the user_badges table which holds the badge information. When a job runs in the background, I get the following error

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException: Call to undefined relationship [userBadge] on model [App\User]. in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/RelationNotFoundException.php:34

Navigating throughout the site I get no issue at all.

This issue occurs when sending an email to the job queue. It happens to all notifications that is sent. Further to this, sometimes the email does get sent but most of the time it doesn't. The code is below for one of the notification

```
class NewFollowUserNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    public $sender;
    public $receiver;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @param User $sender
     * @param User $receiver
     */
    public function __construct(User $sender, User $receiver)
    {
        $this->sender = $sender;
        $this->receiver = $receiver;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param mixed $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        if (Profile::sendEmailNotification('NewFollowUserNotification', $this->receiver)) {
            return ['database', 'mail', 'broadcast'];
        } else {
            return ['database', 'broadcast'];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param mixed $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $user_notifications = UserNotifications::create('NewFollowUserNotification');
        $user_notifications->setUsername($this->receiver->username);
        $user_notifications->setEmailTemplate(EmailTemplate::getDefaultEmail());
        $user_notifications->setButtonUrl(config('app.url').'/member/profiles/'.$this->sender->username);
        $notification = $user_notifications->getEmailNotification();
        $user_notifications->setTags('{receiver_first_name}', $this->receiver->first_name);
        $user_notifications->setTags('{receiver_last_name}', $this->receiver->last_name);
        $user_notifications->setTags('{receiver_full_name}', $this->receiver->first_name . ' ' . $this->receiver->last_name);
        $user_notifications->setTags('{sender_first_name}', $this->sender->first_name);
        $user_notifications->setTags('{sender_last_name}', $this->sender->last_name);
        $user_notifications->setTags('{sender_full_name}', $this->sender->first_name . ' ' . $this->sender->last_name);

        return $user_notifications->sendUserNotification($notification);
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param mixed $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'heading' => 'New contact request',
            'message' => $this->sender->first_name.' '.$this->sender->last_name.
                ' sent you a contact request',
            'link' => '/member/profiles/'.$this->sender->username,
            'username' => $this->sender->username,
            'module' => 'user',
        ];
    }
```

Locally on my own development machine everything works fine.

Comment: you call `userBadge` instead of `user_badge`, try `user_badge`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo I have updated the code

Comment: can you show your code in job

Comment: @DevinE I have updated my question to include the code for the job

Comment: I have a separate Redis server setup for my site and flushing it / deleting all jobs seems to be allowing all jobs to run correctly. We'll keep an eye on this and confirm that this is the solution

Comment: The issue is still occuring even flushing all redis records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was the serialization of models within a job. There are limitations as to how much data jobs can serialize so I ended up passing the id of the model to the job and accessing the necessary information from there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where my queue keeps failing because of `RelationshipNotFound`

I tested with the queue on my staging server and it seemed fine. So it bothered me a lot why I encounter the issue in production. The solution is to restart your queue worker.

**In Laravel, the queue worker loads the necessary classes and executes the job based on the code at the time of processing. If you modify the code that the queue worker relies on, such as changing the logic in a job class or updating dependencies, you'll need to restart the queue worker to ensure it picks up the new changes.**

I was about to rewrite the logic in my Notifications when I remembered I'd had a similar issue before, immediately after I `restarted my queue worker`, the error disappeared.